# implement single sign on on HTML login page to access another application

Tags: html, single-sign-on

I have to implement "Single Sign On" (SSO) in our HTML website so that user can get access to another portal i.e. app.clearstorydata.com. I'm not sure how I can implement it and what I need to do here.

Do I need some kind of SSO login API from app.clearstorydata.com? or Do I need to just pass login and password through the API?

What steps are involved if I need to implement SSO in the HTML website?

Comment: Hi, this question is too broad for the site. Try to implement one yourself and then if you run into an issue, ask about that issue here. "How to" tutorial-like questions are considered off-topic due to their breadth.

Comment: Google some SSO reads and find out if SSO is really needed. In general, SSO is for cross-domain identity exchange.